# Python, Describe.spatialReference errors

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

Having trouble getting my code to work. Keep getting IOError that my parks.shp doesn't exist....not sure I understand what this is saying.

```
import arcpy

mxd = "D:\...\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd"

mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)

dataset = "D:\...\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd\parks.shp"

spatialref = arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference

extent = arcpy.Describe(dataset).extent

for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc):

      df.spatialReference = spatialref
      df.panToExtent()
      df.scale = 15000
      print "\nData frame " + df.name + " contains the following layers:"
      lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "", "", df)
      for lyr in lyrlist:
          print lyr.names 
mapdoc.save() 
del mapdoc
```

Full error message:

File "D:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in **main**.**dict**
  File "D:\CLASSES\Debugging_andErrorHandlingLab\Scripts\Mod3_Script2_Template (2).py", line 12, in 
    spatialref = arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 1234, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 374, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "D:\CLASSES\Debugging_andErrorHandlingLab\Data\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd\parks.shp" does not exist

Comment: Please review the code, since the last line seems mashed up

Comment: Your problem is likely the failure to either escape backslashes or to use "raw" mode (prepend an 'r' before the quote).  So Python is correct -- the *file* "\...\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd\parks.shp" does not exist in directory "D:"

Comment: Code blocks must have FOUR leading spaces.  There's a `{}` button to format it for you.

Comment: I tried the use r"D......shp" as well. No luck. The full error message is to follow.

Comment: Thank you for including the full error.  Now look at what it says.  An MXD is a file.  No shapefile will be inside it as if it were a directory.

Comment: I see. I removed the \parks.shp. This lets the script run easier, but an error is still happening. The new error is, "AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist". I remove this from the end of the line 12 and next error is with .extent...which I also removed.

Answer (score 2):

***LOTS OF ERRORS were fixed*** 
 --.spatialRefernce (no good) .extent(no good), lyrlist, had too many arguments--FIXED

```
import arcpy
mxd = r"D:\CLASSES\Debugging_andErrorHandlingLab\Data\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd"
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
dataset = r"D:\CLASSES\Debugging_andErrorHandlingLab\Data\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd"
spatialref = arcpy.Describe(dataset)
extent = arcpy.Describe(dataset)        df.scale = 15000
    print "\nData frame " + df.name + " contains the following layers:"
    lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "", df)
for lyr in lyrlist:
    print lyr.name
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc):
    df.panToExtent(df.extent)

mapdoc.save()
del mapdoc
```

Answer (score 2):

Locate your shapefile.

The error message says it's in:

`"D:\CLASSES\Debugging_andErrorHandlingLab\Data\TravisCountyAustinTxx.mxd\parks.shp"`

The .MXD can't be a folder, so it's definitely not there.

Perhaps it's in the same folder as the MXD:

`dataset = r"D:\CLASSES\Debugging_andErrorHandlingLab\Data\parks.shp"`